Ali Baba and the 2 urns with black and white balls
Ali Baba is caught by the sultan while stealing his daughter. The sultan is being gentle with him and he offers Ali Baba a chance to regain his liberty. There are 2 urns and m white balls and n black balls. Ali Baba has to put the balls in the 2 urns however he likes with the only condition that no urn is empty. After that the sultan will chose an urn at random and then pick a ball from that urn. If the chosen ball is white, Ali Baba is free to go; otherwise Ali Baba’s head will be at the same level as his legs.
How should Ali Baba divide the balls to maximize his chance of survival?
Source: this problem is from the book "Handbook of Probability -- Ionut Florescu, Ciprian A. Tudor " on page 61 problem 2.33
My approach (though not sure if it's correct):
Put one white ball in the first urn.
Put all the remaining balls (both white and black) in the second urn.
First Urn: Contains only 1 white ball.
Probability of drawing a white ball from the first urn $= 1$ (since there is only one ball and it's white).
Second Urn: Contains $m-1$ white balls and $n$ black balls.
Probability of drawing a white ball from the second urn $= \frac{m-1}{(m-1) + n}$.
Now, the sultan chooses an urn at random with equal probability. Therefore, each urn is chosen with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.
The total probability $P$ of Ali Baba drawing a white ball (and thus surviving) can be calculated as follows:
$P = \frac{1}{2} \times 1 + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{m-1}{m-1+n}
$
$
P = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{m-1}{m-1+n}
$
$
P = \frac{(m-1+n) + (m-1)}{2(m-1+n)}
$
$
P = \frac{2m - 2 + n}{2(m-1+n)}
$
$
P = \frac{2m + n - 2}{2(m-1+n)}
$
Thus, the optimal strategy for Ali Baba is to put one white ball in the first urn and the remaining $m-1$ white balls and $n$ black balls in the second urn. This configuration maximizes his probability of survival. Any help is appreciated it.

You just claim that your solution maximizes the probability. Your calculation does not prove this claim.

@user how should do it?

For example you can consider a general case with $m_1,n_1$ balls in the first urn and $m-m_1,n-n_1$ balls in the second one and demonstrate that the expression has maximum for  $m_1=1,n_1=0$, or resort to a cleverer idea.

@user your idea might work but I’m not sure how I’ll get $m_1=1$ and $n_1=0$. Do I have to calculate the probability every time and then induction? Could you please help me in writing a complete solution?

@user does the proof use derivatives?

Let the number of balls in urns be $u$  and $t-u$, respectively ($t=m+n$). WLOG we can assume $u\le t-u$ or $u\le t/2$. Then for $u>0$ the probability in question is $\frac12P(u)$ with:
$$\begin{align}
P(u)&=\max_{m_1}\left(\frac{m_1}u+\frac{m-m_1}{t-u}\right)=\frac{m}{t-u}+\max_{m_1}\left(m_1\left[\frac1u-\frac1{t-u}\right]\right)\\
&=\frac{m}{t-u}+\left[\frac1u-\frac1{t-u}\right]\max_{m_1}\left(m_1\right)
=\frac{m}{t-u}+\left[\frac1u-\frac1{t-u}\right]\min(u,m)\\
&=\begin{cases}
1+\frac{m-u}{t-u}\ge1,& u\le m\\
\frac mu\le 1,& u\ge m
\end{cases}.
\end{align}$$
This means:
$$\max_u P(u)=\max_{0<u}\left( 1+\frac{m-u}{t-u}\right)=\left[1+\frac{m-u}{t-u}\right]_{u=1}=1+\frac{m-1}{t-1},
$$
i.e. one urn should contain one white ball with all other balls in the other urn.
